# Waiting for function to finish and making sure I am not returning a wrong value

Tags: android, asynchronous, callback

I am fetching information from Firebase remote config and I have a function that returns a boolean after this check. What I want is the ability to wait for the function to finish before the code resumes and returns a value which may not represent the actual true value because the request might take more time to come back than the code running on the device. So I am inside a vicious loop of callbacks that won't help me get what I want. Here is my code snippet -

```
private boolean appIsBelowMinimumAppVersion() {
    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    getMinAppVersion(); // <- at this place the code might take more time to execute than the code after that running 
    return  min_version < currentVersionCode;
  }

  private void getMinAppVersion(){
    FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings settings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(200).build();
    firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(settings);
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
      if (!task.isSuccessful() || !task.isComplete()) {
        //our task is not successful
        return;
      }
      min_version = firebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(RemoteConfigUtil.MIN_VERSION);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `[Handler.Callback][1]` and `[Message][1]` to give the result after your firebase code completed.

```
private boolean appIsBelowMinimumAppVersion() {
    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    getMinAppVersion(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
            // get your min_version value here
            int min_version = message.getData().getInt('min_version');
        }
    });
}

private void getMinAppVersion() {
    FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = 
    FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings settings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(200).build();
    firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(settings);
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener(task 
    -> {
      if (!task.isSuccessful() || !task.isComplete()) {
        //our task is not successful
        min_version = -1;
      }
      min_version = firebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(RemoteConfigUtil.MIN_VERSION);
      Message message = new Message();
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putInt("min_version", min_version);
      message.setData(b);
      callback.handleMessage(message);
    });
}
```

Note: This code for Android API 29